# How to give user access right for Collabnet SubVersion with LDAP user

Tags: collabnet

I would like to define access right to Collabnet Subversion Directory with LDAP domain user. 
eg. LDAP domain user1 only have access to ../svn/Project1
Now using CollabNetSubversionEdge-2.2.1.
What should i configure and set up in subversion for this ? Only want to use LDAP domain user and don't want to create user in SubVerion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to follow these steps
1. Log into the console.
2. Get into the Repository tab and click 'Access'.
3. Edit the rules to include

```
[Project1:/]
user1 = rw
```

it will give read write access to Project1 repository for user1 domain.

Alternatively, you can modify the svn_access_file (under {installation home}/data/conf directory ) directly. Once the subversion edge is integrated with the LDAP, on the first login to the console using the LDAP user crdential will create the user for use in the subversion edge server.

I hope it helps.